# Many people value me above their brains

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Most value me above their brain
>   or seek me for arms that are great
>   Maxwell introduced me yet again
>   As did Ward, though a century late
>
> One word and the cloud I will reach you
>   or get to your house on the ice
>   If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes
>   I'll be playing with
>   balls here at Rice
>
> What/Who am I?

(Hmm... it sort of got away from me at the end there.  I swear it's nothing dirty.)  This should be pretty easy, so preference goes to the answer that explains all the clues.

Comment: Some of these clues seemed familiar to me, so let me know if I am repeating.  I couldn't find the answer by a simple search, but perhaps spoiler tags are shielded(?).

Comment: "One word and the cloud I will reach you" ... kind of grammatically ambiguous. Any reconsideration on that line?

Comment: Something to do with Electromagnetism? Maxwell gave the Classical theory of electromagnetism(1865) while Ward's Identity helped in Quantum ElectroDynamics in the 1950s(?)

Comment: @Arcane Each clue/line is from a different realm.  Maxwell is correct, but I was thinking of a different Ward.  (Very good observation, though.)

Comment: Hint:  Most people picked up on the fact that each line is a separate clue.  I should note that each line is from a different realm or way of referring to the same word.  People so far have come close on many of the clues without hitting on the actual word.  Looking at other people's answers might help you narrow down the right realm:  1(ivanhoe kinda), 2 (cst1992), 3(Arcane/Lafexlos), 4 (this one is hard), 5 (Edd), 6 (no one), 7 (Lafexlos), 8 (this one is hard, but Lafexlos has a handle on it)

Comment: As of this posting, the answer appears exactly once on this page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Plausible answer:

> Curl

```
Most value me above their brain
```

Two possibilities here:
1.

> This can refer to the use of a curling iron.  Nearly always used ABOVE one's head, rather than elsewhere on their body.

2.

> Curly head hair, rather than...other....curly...hair..
>  Additionally, curly hair seems to be more expensive to maintain, than others.
>  Examples:
>  https://phoebeparke.com/2012/11/13/expensive-curls-the-price-scale-of-curly-hair-rinse-out-conditioners/
>  http://www.curlynikki.com/2011/08/is-natural-hair-more-expensive-response.html
>  There's more that you can look up

```
or seek me for arms that are great
```

> [Curls](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/dumbbell-bicep-curl) for bodybuilding

```
Maxwell introduced me yet again
```

> *Maxwell*'s equations include equations regarding [circulation and curls](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/curl/curl.php) $\triangledown$

```
As did Ward, though a century late
```

> Steve *Ward* designed the [Curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28programming_language%29) programming language

```
One word and the cloud I will reach you
```

> You can use the REST API and simple [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) messages to get data from an online *cloud*.

```
or get to your house on the ice
```

> [Curling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curling) is sport involving sliding stones towards a circular marked area, called a *house*, on a sheet of ice.

```
If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes
```

> A good surfer can [shoot the curl](http://www.cougartown.com/surf-slang.html) without falling off of a wave.

```
I'll be playing with balls here at Rice
```

> [Robert F. Curl](https://chemistry.rice.edu/FacultyDetail.aspx?RiceID=589), of Rice University, shared the Nobel Prize, for Chemistry with two others, for the discovery of $\large c_{60}$, a.k.a. buckminsterfullerene or "bucky *ball*."

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Electromagnetic wave

Most value me above their brain

> The radiation emitted from cellphones (or other electronic devices) cause brain damages yet we still use them.

or seek me for arms that are great

> There are hair removal techniques that uses electromagnetic waves

Maxwell introduced me yet again
As did Ward, though a century late

> In comments @Arcane explained it really well, so I am just copy/pasting it.
>  Maxwell gave the Classical theory of electromagnetism(1865) while Ward's Identity helped in Quantum ElectroDynamics in the 1950s(?)

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> When you talk on phone, waves carrying the info transmits through air.

or help you get home on the ice

> No idea. Maybe electromagnetic skates?

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> A reference to *waves* at sea/ocean.

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> *There is a belief* that rice plant can absorb radiation(couldn't find the article so I wrote there is belief)
>  or maybe a reference to Rice University but other than random electromagnetic wave theory courses, couldn't managed to find connection.
>
>  p.s. since English is not my first language I probably missed some technical terms. If you know any, feel free to edit them in.

Comment: Not the answer, but I like your thoughts and explanations.  Like Arcane, you are very close on the third line/clue.  Every line is from a different realm, though.  The answer is one word.

Comment: You are also the closest of anyone so far on 8, and your 7 is very good.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it might be:

> a plane

So...I'm new at this, so don't hit me too hard pls :(
Explanation:

> Most value me above their brain=> planes fly in the sky, above most of the brains (not the pilot/passenger's  ones tho)
>  or seek me for arms that are great=>has good arms, as in weapons
>  no clue about these 2 lines:
>  Maxwell introduced me yet again
>  As did Ward, though a century late
>  One word and the cloud I will reach you=>fly, and the plane is above the clouds
>  or help you get home on the ice=> if there is ice, surely you can fly to avoid it from cracking? :D
>  If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes=> D-Day reference?
>  I'll be playing with balls here at Rice=>Hiroshima Reference?

Comment: You can add two spaces behind each line to make a multi-line spoiler / quote block. `>! Line 1  `  & `>! Line 2  `.

Comment: I've edited it. Have a look.

Comment: The "cloud" clue fits, but the others don't.  Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: Clarification for those constructing the answer from other answers: the "cloud" clue here fits, but not in the manner I intended.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer:

> Good body, fitness, or muscles, use whichever one you like

Most value me above their brain

> Many people in the world are fitness-cravers, even some who are not very well-educated

or seek me for arms that are great

> Obviously.

Maxwell introduced me yet again
As did Ward, though a century late

> Both Maxwell and Ward are gym and fitness brands.

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> No idea.

or help you get home on the ice

> A fitter person will have a higher chance of wading through thick snow.

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> Guys like to sport their bodies at the beach

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> No idea.

Comment: You are closer than others on the second clue, but this is not the answer.  Sorry.  (Interesting observation on the gym equipment brands. I didn't know that.)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> Power

Most value me above their brain

> People value power over knowledge

or seek me for arms that are great

> Power lifting or otherwise being strong (powerful)

Maxwell introduced me yet again

> Maxwell's power equations

As did Ward, though a century late

> Not entirely sure about this one

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> Electrical power makes "the cloud" work

or help you get home on the ice

> Either 4WD power helping with icy roads, or a reference to the ICE (German electric train)

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> Powershot underwater camera

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> Something to do with Powerball? (non-US here so maybe a reference I don't get)

Comment: Good thoughts and explanations here, too; but not the right answer.

Comment: You are getting to the right idea for the 5th line, btw.

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be:

> Steel

Most value me above their brain

> Steel helmets protect your head (and indirectly your brain)

or seek me for arms that are great
Maxwell introduced me yet again
As did Ward, though a century late

> Might be a reference to the coat of arms of noble families. As a matter of fact searches for "Maxwell coat of arms" and "Ward coat of arms" reveal 2 coat of arms that share an identical feature: a steel helmet

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> I have no idea

or help you get home on the ice

> The blades of skates or sleighs are made from steel

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> Probably a reference to World War II D-Day fighting where soldiers of both parties shot (steel) bullets.

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> Ball shaped rice cookers made from stainless steel, a way more peaceful use of the material as opposed to making bullets (I feel this connection is enforced by the if/else pattern of the last 2 verses)

Comment: You are the closest of anyone so far with regards to the first line.  The other explanations are interesting, but not in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> Gravity

Most value me above their brain

> Woe to he who doesn't pay attention to things falling on him!

or seek me for arms that are great

> Curls, presses, flys, etc. use gravity as resistance for weight training.

Maxwell introduced me yet again

> Maxwell's equations are peripherally related to space-time and thus gravity.

As did Ward, though a century late

> Not sure about this one.

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> Rain falling?

or help you get home on the ice

> Assuming you live downhill, wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> Waves crashing on the shore.

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> [This dude in a ball pit](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/21/rice-university-ball-pit_n_6520748.html) at Rice University.

Comment: Two, 3, 7, and 8 are in the right direction, yet the answer is not correct. Though, in a certain sense, you are infinitely closer than anyone so far.

Answer (score 2):

## Not an answer

I've collected the bits and pieces that OP says are closest to the solution for the sake of easy reference.

---

1. **Most value me above their brain**

   > *(ivanhoe kinda)* Steel helmets protect your head (and indirectly your brain)
2. **or seek me for arms that are great**

   > (Dan Russell) Curls, presses, flys, etc. use gravity as resistance for weight training.
3. **Maxwell introduced me yet again**

   > (Dan Russell) Maxwell's equations are peripherally related to space-time and thus gravity.
4. **As did Ward, though a century late**

   > (this one is hard)
5. **One word and the cloud I will reach you**

   > (Edd) Electrical power makes "the cloud" work
6. **or help you get home on the ice**

   > (no one)
7. **If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes**

   > (Dan Russell) Waves crashing on the shore.
8. **I'll be playing with balls here at Rice**

   > (Dan Russell) [This dude in a ball pit](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/21/rice-university-ball-pit_n_6520748.html) at Rice University.

Comment: Dan Russel has surpassed these in 2, 3, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> A Wave

Most value me above their brain:

> Wavy hair

or seek me for arms that are great

> Not sure but this could be listening to music?

Maxwell introduced me yet again
As did Ward, though a century late

> Maxwell's EM wave theory which Ward expanded on.

One word and the cloud I will reach you

> Say something and the sound waves will travel everywhere

or get to your house on the ice

> an ocean wave pushing the ice? not too sure

If I'm not being shot by the beach dudes

> also explained by Lafexlos, taking pictures of the ocean/waves?

I'll be playing with balls here at Rice

> ? no idea